# iPhone: NSTimer Countdown (Display Minutes:Seconds)

Tags: iphone, nstimer, countdown

I have my timer code set up, and it's all kosher, but I want my label to display "Minutes : seconds" instead of just seconds.

```
-(void)countDown{

    time -= 1;

    theTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", time];

    if(time == 0)
    {
    [countDownTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

I've already set "time" to 600, or 10 minutes. However, I want the display to show 10:59, 10:58, etc. until it reaches zero.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int seconds = time % 60;
int minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
theTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: That's great! However, once the seconds gets below ten it shows "9:9", "9:8", etc.

Is there a way to make that "9:09", "9:08"?

Comment: Sure. `NSString *padZero = @""; if(seconds < 10) padZero = @"0"; theTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%@%i",minutes,padZero,seconds];`

Comment: I'd rather use printf formatting for padding numbers like that:  `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d", minutes, seconds]`

Comment: guys how to declare time.

Answer (score 0):

By the time, I was made a little upgrade of first answer, it removed conflicts that associated from `NSInteger` and `int`:

```
NSInteger secondsLeft = 987;
int second = (int)secondsLeft % 60;
int minutes = ((int)secondsLeft - second) / 60;
theTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, second]];
```